# Quarkus FileUpload is null in MultipartForm from Angular post request

Tags: angular, file-upload, multipartform-data, quarkus

For front-end upload I followed the tutorial from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/angular-file-upload/

The problem is that Quarkus does not receive input file (it is null)

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.multipart.FileUpload.uploadedFile()" because "input.file" is null
**

code backend:

```
    public static class FileUploadInput
    {
        @FormParam("file")
        public FileUpload file;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response getAndEncryptPdf(@MultipartForm FileUploadInput input){
        InputStream uploadedInputStream;
        try {
            log.info("here", input);
            uploadedInputStream = Files.newInputStream(input.file.uploadedFile());

            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(uploadedInputStream);
            *rest of the code..*
```

code frontend:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <input class="form-control" type="file" 
          (change)="onChange($event)">

  <button (click)="onUpload()" 
      class="btn btn-success">
      Upload
  </button>
</div>
```

```
  sendPDF(formData: FormData){
    console.log(formData)
    return this.http.post<any>("https://file.io", formData, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      }),
      observe: 'response'//, responseType:'blob' as 'json'
    });
  }

  // On file Select
  onChange(event) {
      this.file = event.target.files[0];
  }
  
    // OnClick of button Upload
  onUpload() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file',  this.file );
    this.sendDataService.sendPDF(formData).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log('PDF uploaded successfully:', response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error uploading PDF:', error);
      }
    );
   }
```

Comment: let form = document.getElementById('id_of_your_form')! as HTMLFormElement;
   let formData = new FormData(form);   Then just use return this.http.post<any>("https://file.io", formData).... (no need to append anything, no need to set headers)